# how can Reduce the pressure from main page of gps tracking

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

im developing gps tracking system with asp.net mvc  and sql server db first , i have question about main page that show all device on map, in this page fetch many data from database and and process it and after every 15 seconds i should  refresh this page
how can i Reduce the pressure on this page?
If you have an idea or a specific way to reduce the pressure on this page please guide me

Comment: `how can i Reduce the pressure on this page?` refresh the page every 30 seconds instead?

Comment: Pressure how? Do you get a lot of requests within a certain timeframe? Is the database call too heavy? Is the response too large (bandwidth issue)?

Comment: when the main page wants load and intialaize ,may be some company have many cars, when i want intialaize the page i should get many data from data base   and Some data needs to be processed

Comment: @mohamad can we see the data model that you're dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) which implements [web sockets](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets); unlike what you're doing which is polling (constantly requesting data from the server every 15s or so), with websockets you don't have to initiate a request again and again, as the server will be the one send data to any connected client **IF there is data to be sent.**

It's a popular C# library so you'll find a lot of tutorials here and there.

Comment: i cant use signalr  because  base our  system on tcp/ip

Comment: @mohamad Oh I see. Imma follow your explanation in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

diagram of  main tables,but i insert row data of gps device in another table but last log table  is live data for display last state of carrier [image]